# Can't set log channel to null in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, logging

I'm using three environment files for testing - `.env.testing` for unit/feature tests, `.env.dusk.local` for local Dusk tests, and `.env.dusk.testing` for CI/CD Dusk tests. I'm trying to set the log channel for all of these to `null`, because I don't need tests to log anything at all.

When I replace the logging variables in these files with:

```
LOG_CHANNEL=null
```

...and try to run the Dusk tests, I get the following in my logs:

```
[2023-10-26 18:38:28] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [] is not defined. at D:\\Path\\To\\Site\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager.php:210)
[stacktrace]
...
```

I know this should be possible based on [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/logging#available-channel-drivers), and I've confirmed that I have the following set up in `logging.php`:

```
'null' => [
    'driver' => 'monolog',
    'handler' => NullHandler::class,
],
```

I've also run `php artisan optimize:clear` to rule out the configuration cache. For what it's worth, I did use Laravel Shift to upgrade to Laravel 9 recently, in case this is a dependency or version-specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel doesn't consider every environment variable as string, there are special keywords that will be converted to other types. In your case, `null` seems to be converted effectively to a `null` value inside Laravel.

Try to change your channel name to something else (like `nullable` for example):

```php
// in environment files use LOG_CHANNEL=nullable

'nullable' => [
    'driver' => 'monolog',
    'handler' => NullHandler::class,
],
```

Or you can also try to wrap `null` inside double quotes in your environment files:

```
LOG_CHANNEL="null"
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/configuration#environment-variable-types

Another solution, also this seems to be not well documented, is to use `null` driver like this:

```php
'nullable' => [
    'driver' => 'null',
    'handler' => NullHandler::class, // probably not needed
],
```

Comment: Changing the channel name does appear to work weirdly, despite the documentation saying `null` should work and despite it being [the default](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/config/logging.php) in Laravel 9. This therefore looks like a bug. Either way I'm glad it's sorted, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alberto's solution is the way to go here, but I don't recommend renaming the main null logger just in case it breaks other things relying on it - instead, I ended up creating a custom logger in `logging.php` which also uses Monolog's NullHandler:

```
    'null' => [
        'driver' => 'monolog',
        'handler' => NullHandler::class,
    ],

    # Add this
    'silent' => [
        'driver' => 'monolog',
        'handler' => NullHandler::class,
    ],
```

Then using the new logger in my environment files:

```
LOG_CHANNEL=silent
```